# Transfer User Control to a WPF custom control

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls

Ok, I have a user control, which I want to transfer into a WPF custom control.

The user control has code behind file, so I can directly register to events of control:
For Example:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" 
                 Name="valueBox"                 
                 TextAlignment="Right" TextChanged="valueBox_TextChanged" PreviewKeyDown="valueBox_PreviewKeyDown" />
```

And the corresponding valueBox_TextChanged event in the code behind is:

```
 private void valueBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        var positiveWholeNum = new Regex(@"^-?\d+$");
        if (!positiveWholeNum.IsMatch(textBox.Text) || int.Parse(textBox.Text) < 0)
        {
            textBox.Text = "0";
        }
        NumericValue = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text);

        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ValueChangedEvent));

    }
```

Now, when I try to turn this into a custom control, I have a Theme Folder, with a Generic.Xaml file. And file: MyCustomControl.cs

In Generic.Xaml, I've written (I derive from Control)

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" 
                 Name="valueBox"                 
                 TextAlignment="Right"  />
```

and in the cs file:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        AttachTextBox();
    }


 protected TextBox TextBox;

    private void AttachTextBox()
    {
        var textBox = GetTemplateChild("valueBox") as TextBox;

        if (textBox != null)
        {
            TextBox = textBox;
        }
    }
```

Now, how do I write a replacement for valueBox_TextChanged which is written in the user control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the code for the valueBox_TextChanged event handler in the codebehind of your generic.xaml file. To create a code behind fiel for Generic.XAML follow the below steps.

1. Add a file named generic.xaml.cs

   ```
   Right click on themes folder and select new class

   Name it as generic.xaml.cs
   ```
2. Change the definition of the class inside generic.xaml.cs as partial
   class generic :ResourceDictionary //This class should inherit from
   ResourceDictionary
3. Link this code behind file to Gereric.xaml by using x:Class

Now you can write code for your generic.xaml elements in the generic.xaml.cs file.

For More Info: [Code behind for Generic.XAML](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.ae/2007/09/writing-code-behind-for-genericxaml.html)